# Typing the reduce method

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am trying to add typing to the reduce method. So I'm looking at something like this:

```
interface tmp {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

const a: tmp = {
  bar: 'value',
  foo: 'value2',
}

const b: tmp = Object.keys(a).reduce((acc,key: string) => {
  acc[key] = key;
  return acc;
}, {})
```

The problem is, I'm getting this error:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'tmp': foo, bar

Which is true, but not really. How can I make this setup work?

I tried doing this:

type keysType = { [key in keyof typeof ParameterLabels]: string };
export const ParameterNames: ParameterInputs = Object.keys(ParameterLabels).reduce(
(acc, key) => {
acc[key] = key;
return acc;
},
{},
);

But now I'm getting this error:

> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keysType'.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'keysType': parameterType, type, name, minValue, and 6 more.

on passing of the accumulator.

Comment: Use the generic - or, as I'd prefer, use `Object.fromEntries`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. It's just a way around the reduce. The type error still persists.

Comment: `Object.keys` has an implicit type `string` for keys, so you have no option but to cast,.  So this might help, ->  `const b = Object.keys(a).reduce((acc, key) => { acc[key as keyof tmp] = key; return acc; }, {} as tmp);`  The trick here is to cast the accumulator as `tmp`, and then use `keyof tmp` so that `acc[]` is correct.